# I set the limit to all containers in all namespaces . How to get Prometheus query for memory utilisation in a percentage

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager, grafana-alerts

i set request and limit for all the containers for all namespaces. Looking for Prometheus query to create Prometheus alert using Grafana if memory utilization is more than 80% (Percentage)

implemented request and limit as per below.

```
   resources:
      requests:
        cpu: "53m"
        memory: "46Mi"
      limits:
        cpu: "340m"
        memory: "70Mi"
```

I tried below query but did not help.

```
container_memory_working_set_bytes{name!~".*prometheus.*", image!="", container_name!="POD"} / 
container_spec_memory_limit_bytes{name!~".*prometheus.*", image!="", container_name!="POD"} * 100
```

Comment: Drive-by comment [Never set CPU limit](https://twitter.com/thockin/status/1134193838841401345) and  [CPU limits on Kubernetes are an anti-pattern](https://home.robusta.dev/blog/stop-using-cpu-limits)

Comment: You want to exclude (a) anything less than `0.8`; (b) those values where there's no `limits.memory` which will be a zero divisor and a `+inf` result. So, you could try: `0.8<(container_memory_working_set_bytes{name!~".*prometheus.*", image!="", container!="POD"} / 
container_spec_memory_limit_bytes{name!~".*prometheus.*", image!="", container!="POD"})<+Inf`. I think (!?) there's no `container_name` label but `container` and I think it's unlikely you'll have a value of `POD` (and an empty `image` value)!?

Comment: Hi @DazWilkin thanks for your quick response. 
i tried your query but it's not showing memory utilization in percentage. I don't want to exclude anything. 

i want to create alert in Grafana to monitor all containers which is running under multiple namespaces. Whenever any container memory utilization is more than 80% it should fire alert and send slack notification. I am stuck with query to create Graph and send alert notification.